# glib callbacks and thread safety

Tags: thread-safety, gtk, pygtk, glib

*Note that I am using Python but this could apply to any other bindings from glib.*

I have a class that sets up several sockets connections via `glib.io_add_watch()` and a callback method called `foo()`.  In addition, I have a `glib.idle_add()` callback to a method called `bar()`.  `foo()` creates or update a list (class member) of elements that can be any value including None.  `bar()` removes any None item form the above list -- we done with those, we no longer care.  In effect it cleans things up.

Does glib grantee that only one callback will be called at any one time per thread?

If I were to run this code so that `foo()` is in thread one and `bar()` in thread two, there would be a race condition.  I assume that a simple mutex would solve this but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Callbacks added via `g_io_add_watch` and `g_add_idle` are executed in the main loop's thread regardless of what thread they were added from.

Comment: What you are saying seem to indicate that a callback will only run in one thread so it is safe to modify any collection within said callback without resorting to external mutex?  Is that right?

Comment: Yes.  Both callbacks will be run from the same thread so there is no chance of them being run at the same time.